# Solving for particular solution to the Bloch wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

It has been a long time since I've worked on periodic boundary conditions involving the Bloch theorem (quantum mechanics) so I am hoping to get some help on my next step.

Suppose I have a lattice with period $a$ with potential $V(x) = v_{0}\sum \delta (x-na)$. At any boundary the potential is infinite) and any interval between two adjacent boundary the potential is zero.

[image]

1. **General solution to the wavefunctions**

**On the interval $x \in (0, +a):$**

on this interval $v(x) = 0$ by design.

Using the Time - independent Schrodinger equation: $-\frac{h^{2}}{2m}\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}} \psi_{I}(x) = E\psi_{I}(x)$

Two complex roots: the general solution is $\psi_{I}(x) = Ae^{i\tilde{k}x} + Be^{-i\tilde{k}x}$

**On the interval $x \in (-a, 0):$**

on this interval $v(x) = 0$ by design and since this interval is just a repeat of the interval $I$, the Bloch wave can be invoked.

The Bloch wave has a form $\psi(x) = e^{ikx}\phi(x)$ where $\phi(x)$ is periodic.

$\psi_{I}(x - (-a)) = \psi_{I}(x + a) = e^{ik(x+a)}\phi(x+a) = ... e^{ika}\psi_{II}(x)$.

The general solution for $\psi_{II}(x):$ $\psi_{II}(x) = e^{-ika}\psi_{I}(x+a) = e^{-ika}[Ae^{i\tilde{k}(x+a)} + Be^{-i\tilde{k}(x+a)}]$

2. **Applying the boundary conditions**

The boundary conditions are

2.1 continuity of wavefunction: $\psi_{I}(0) = \psi_{II}(0)$

2.2 continuity of the first spatial derivative of the wavefunction: $$\psi_{I}^{'}(0) = \psi_{II}^{"}(0)$$

2.1 yields $A-Ae^{-ika}e^{i\tilde{k}a} + B - Be^{-ika}e^{-i\tilde{k}a} = 0$

2.2 requires $\psi_{I}^{'}(0) - \psi_{II}^{"}(0) = \frac{2mv_{0}}{\bar{h}}\psi(0)$ to give

$A(1 - e^{i(k-\tilde{k}a)-\frac{2mv_{0}}{\bar{h}^{2}i\tilde{k}}}) + B(-1 + e^{i(k-\tilde{k})a} - \frac{2mv_{0}}{\bar{h}^{2}i \tilde{k}}) = 0$

The matrix representation for 2.1 and 2.2 can be expressed as

\begin{bmatrix}
    (1 - e^{-ika}e^{i\tilde{k}a}), (1 - e^{-ika}e^{-i\tilde{k}a}) \\
    (1 - e^{i(k-\tilde{k})a} - \frac{2mv_{0}}{\bar{h}^{2}i\tilde{k}}), (-1 + e^{i(k-\tilde{k})a }-\frac{2mv_{0}}{\bar{h}^{2}i\tilde{k}})
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}
    A \\
    B
\end{bmatrix}

=

\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}

In proceeding with solving the determinant, I did not arrive at the correct answer which was likely due to a wrong direction I made in my workings. Any help to assist me with arriving at the solution for the Bloch wavefunction is greatly appreciated.